# Mixing ... with formal args in s4 generic method

Tags: r, ellipsis, r-s4

From `?dotsMethods`:

```
 Beginning with version 2.8.0 of R, S4 methods can be dispatched
 (selected and called) corresponding to the special argument “...”.
 Currently, “...” cannot be mixed with other formal arguments:
 either the signature of the generic function is “...” only, or it
 does not contain “...”.  (This restriction may be lifted in a
 future version.)
```

Here is some code from the EBImage package:

```
## image IO, display
setGeneric ("image", function (x, ...) standardGeneric("image") )

## statistics
setGeneric ("hist", function (x, ...) standardGeneric("hist") )
```

This is apparently violating the `“...” cannot be mixed with other formal arguments` rule. Does this mean the restriction has already been lifted but undocumented?

Answer (score 5):

The key word in the section you quote is 'dispatched'. Here

```
setGeneric("foo", function(x, ...) standardGeneric("foo"))
```

you can write methods based on the class of 'x'.

```
.A = setClass("A", "integer")
.B = setClass("B", "integer")
setMethod("foo", "A", function(x, ...) "foo,A-method")
```

The '...' are still available to be used, e.g., to provide method-specific arguments, but there is no dispatch available for "..."

```
setMethod("foo", "B", function(x, barg, ...) sprintf("barg=%d", barg))
```

with

```
> foo(.B(), barg=123)
[1] "barg=123"
```

This is how EBImage is using "...", and this is a very common use case.

Here

```
setGeneric("bar", function(...) standardGeneric("bar"))
```

you can write methods that dispatch on "...", provided all classes are the same

```
setMethod("bar", "A", function(...) "bar,A-method")
```

with

```
> bar(.A(), .A())
[1] "bar,A-method"
> bar(.A(), .B())
Error in standardGeneric("bar") : 
  no method or default matching the "..." arguments in bar(.A(), .B())
> setMethod("bar", c("A", "B"), function(...) "bar,A,B-method")
Error in matchSignature(signature, fdef) : 
  more elements in the method signature (2) than in the generic signature (1) for function 'bar'
```

The above use implicit rules to determine the signature, and the arguments for dispatch are displayed by `getGeneric()` where the output indicates 'Methods may be defined for arguments: ', e.g.,

```
> getGeneric("foo")
standardGeneric for "foo" defined from package ".GlobalEnv"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("foo")
<environment: 0x2ba550a0>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("foo")  for currently available ones.
> getGeneric("bar")
standardGeneric for "bar" defined from package ".GlobalEnv"

function (...) 
standardGeneric("bar")
<environment: 0x2c127e58>
Methods may be defined for arguments: ...
Use  showMethods("bar")  for currently available ones.
```

R seems to let you define generics that dispatch on x mixed with ...

```
> setGeneric("baz", function(x, ...) standardGeneric("baz"), 
             signature=c("x", "..."))
[1] "baz"
```

but actually that's not the case

```
> getGeneric("baz")
standardGeneric for "baz" defined from package ".GlobalEnv"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("baz")
<environment: 0x2c704cc0>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("baz")  for currently available ones.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `...` with other formal arguments in `s4` generics. You should remember to include it as one of the arguments to your `setMethod` function as well.